# CQL3 Query is returning a row with null key

Tags: groovy, cassandra, astyanax, cql3

I'm very new to Cassandra and trying out Astyanax/CQL3 for some simple use cases. I am attempting to retrieve data from a simple table using Astyanax and CQL3 on Cassandra version 1.2 from a Groovy application.

I have the following column family (table):

```
CREATE TABLE t_index_credential (
  id varchar,
  versions map<timestamp,varchar>,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

The following rows exist in the table:

```
 id  | versions
-----+---------------------------------
 xyz | {2001-01-01 00:00:00-0500: 1.0}
```

This is how I'm querying the data:

```
def id = "xyz"
def cfName = "t_index_credential"
def mapSerializer = new MapSerializer<Date,String>(DateType.instance, UTF8Type.instance)
def strSerializer = StringSerializer.get()

def cf = ColumnFamily.newColumnFamily(cfName, strSerializer, mapSerializer)
def cql = "SELECT * FROM ${cfName} WHERE id = '${id}';"

def query = keyspace.prepareQuery(cf).withCql(cql)
def result = query.execute().getResult()

result.getRows().each { row ->
  println "rowKey: " + row.getKey()
}
```

The output of this is:

```
rowKey: null
```

Attempting to access any of the columns in the row results in the following:

```
result.getRows().each { row ->
  row.getColumns().each { col ->
    println col.dump()
  }
}

org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.MarshalException: Not enough bytes to read a map
```

It feels as if I'm missing something very simple. Am I doing anything right?

Comment: I'm getting the same behavior too

Comment: same here. The row key is included in the cols though